# Apache won't start after upgrade to V6R1

Tags: apache-2.2, ibm-midrange

Platform: OS/400 V6R1, IBM i

After upgrade to V6R1, one of our Apache instances will not start. It appears to die silently; DSPJOBLOG yields nothing, /www//logs/error* are all empty, and a WRKSBSJOB QHTTPSVR command shows no leftover jobs or spool files.

Any ideas on where else we can look for some insight into where the failure is occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WRKOUTQ QEZJOBLOG

There was a spool file left over there, notified us of a syntax error in the .conf file.